# Rails: Find with join model - How to?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I have the following models associations which I want to use in order to do some searches of **players**:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_many :abilities
 has_many :sports, :through => :abilities
 ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :player
...
end

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :sport
  has_one :level
  ...
end

class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :category_sports 

  has_many :abilities
  has_many :players, :through => :abilities
  ...
end

class CategorySport < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :sports 
end
```

I have a form where a user can fill two inputs: **city** and **sport**

The city field is in the User model as (`@user.city`) and the sport field can be either in CategorySport as (`@category_sport.name`) or in the Sport model as (`@sport.name`).

Right now I have the following to perform the search in the **Player** model:

```
def search
  self.find(:all,:include => 'user',:conditions => ['users.city LIKE ?', "%#{city}%"])
end
```

I would like to know how would I add the join model (ability) and related (sport, categorysport) in this query in order to find by sport too.  So, not just find for user city but also by sport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def search
  self.includes(:user, :abilities => {:sport => :category_sports}).
    where(['users.city LIKE ? OR category_sports.name=? OR sports.name=?', 
      "%#{city}%", sport, sport])
end
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If the city is not LIKE any of the records it doesn't return anything...

Comment: Do you mean you get incorrect results ONLY when there's no match in `users`? That's weird. Can I see the generated SQL?